# Module scss ampersand class selector not working

Tags: reactjs, webpack, sass, css-modules, react-css-modules

I have a simple scss file with

```
.navItem {
  cursor: pointer;
    
  &.active {
    color: $primaryPurple;
  }
    
  &:hover {
    color: $primaryPurple;
  }
    
  span {
    margin-left: 10px;
  }
}
```

For some reason, the `:hover` works but `.active` doesn't work. As you can see in the image below, `li` clearly has the active class but I don't see the font color css changed.

[image]

Comment: Just make sure the color property isn't getting overriden by some parent element also, there seems to be a difference in the naming of the class nav-item you have used in html and sass file

Comment: Sorry I forgot to specify but this is React module scss, so that's why you see the weird names. And nothing is overwriting the color style. The selector simply doesn't work. I am not sure how to get it working for React module scss.

Comment: How does the compiled CSS look like?

Comment: I am using create-react-app there is a whole discussion about how getting that compiles CSS is complicated. https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/790

Comment: I am just trying to see if anyone has used module scss before and how they would do what I want to do based on their experience. Surely module scss is used a lot?

Comment: The class name is the HTML is `nav-item` and it's trying to be declared in the CSS as `.navItem`. Don't think it's the issue but just checking.

Comment: Dear @jiminssy, maybe the ticked answer is true but trust me, the exact issue comes from `css-modules` please read my answer, you can find all reasons.

Comment: @AmerllicA Thanks I've selected your answer as the solution.

Comment: Dear @jiminssy, Thanks for your care about Stack Overflow, I leave some upvote to your posts for appreciate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**TL;DR**: Pass the name as a JavaScript Object, not like a simple string.

Actually, this issue comes from the `css-modules` configuration. Obviously, based on the `AdminSideBar_navItem__1aFBc` in the embed picture. your `css-modules` configuration in the Webpack config is:

```js
// webpack config

module.exports = {
  ~~~
  module: {
    ~~~

    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: 'style-loader',
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'css-loader',
              options: {
                modules: true,
                importLoaders: 1,
                localIdentName: '[name]_[local]_[hash:base64:5]', // <=== Attention to this line
                sourceMap: true,
              }
            },
            ~~~
          ],
       }),
    ],
  },
  ~~~
};
```

So, when you are using `css-modules` it means you will have so professional advantages like a more compressed css bundle file or full hashed unreadably uglified bundle. for these benefits, you should use CSS class names like a JavaScript object, pay attention to the following ReactJS code alongside using `css-modules`:

```js
import React from 'react';
import cn from 'classnames'; // <=== install it to have easy coding
import styles from '[pathToScssFiles]/styles.scss';

const MyComponent = ({ isActive }) => (
  <li className={cn(styles.navItem, isActive && styles.active)} />
);
```

I hope, you understand my point, you passed the `styles.active` as a simple string: `"active"`. so `css-modules` cannot get your class name as an object and pass it exactly like what it got, as a simple string, hence, `"active" **BUT** in the CSS bundle file the` css-modules`use the`'[name]*[local]*[hash:base64:5]'` pattern to deform its name.

Your `:hover` should work and it works because anyone cannot change it, it's a pseudo-class.

For sure, write a weird property for `.active`:

```
.navItem {
  cursor: pointer;
    
  &.active {
    fill: yellow;
  }
```

Now seek for the `fill: yellow` in the CSS bundle that Webpack makes for you. you see it is:

```css
.AdminSideBar_navItem__1aFBc .AdminSideBar_active__9be2a {
  fill: yellow;
}
```

**Note:** the `~~~` means etc.

Answer (score 2):

Providing you jsx code would help, but I will take a guess that you use `active` as a string literal, so your code looks like

```
import styles from './componentName.module.css';

// and then in the component

<li className={`nav-item ${styles.AdminSideBar_navItem} ${whateverCondition ? 'active' : ''}`}>
     ...children...
</li>
```

The problem here is that `active` class also has a suffix just like `AdminSideBar_navItem`. And in order to make it work you need to access it the same way you access `AdminSideBar_navItem`. So the code should be

```
<li className={`nav-item ${styles.AdminSideBar_navItem} ${whateverCondition ? styles.active : ''}`}>
     ...children...
</li>
```

and in html you will see

```
 <li class="nav-item AdminSideBar_navItem_abcd active_bcde">
```

I dropped a simple example in [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sparkling-fire-x0vtw?file=/src/App.js), you can play around with it and see how it works.